# find the dim S.

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem taken from Apostol calculas Volume $2$ page No: $13$ books

Let $P$ denote the linear space of all real polynomials of degree $\le n$, where $n$ is fixed. let $ S$ denote the set of all polynomials $f$ in $P$, satisfying the condition given below . find the  dim S.

$1.$$f$ is even.

$2.$ $f$ is odd.

My attempt : we know  that dim $P_n = n+1$

I thinks if $f$  is even then dim $S= \frac{n}{2}$

if $f$ is odd then dim $S= \frac{n+1}{2}$

Is its true ?

Comment: No. Set of even even f $\subseteq $ Set of all f. How come dim (set of even f) $=2n \gt n+1?$

Comment: oks @Koro i have edit its

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $n$ is even, say $n=2k$ 
*Even $f$ will be of the type $ c+c_1x^2+c_2x^4+...c_kx^{2k}$ hence dim(S) =$k+1=n/2+1$
**Odd $f$ will be of the type $d_1x+d_3x^3+...+d_{2k-1}x^{2k-1}$, hence dim(S) =$k=n/2$

Similarly consider, case 2: $n$ is odd.

PS: * because even $ f(x) =\frac{ f(x) +f(-x)} {2}$
** odd $f(x) =\frac{f(x) - f(-x)} {2}$

Comment: thanks u koro Got its now